# How to get random images from NASA API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
const PictureOfTheDay = () => {
  const [fetchedImage, setFetchedImage] = useState('');
  const imageHandler = (name) => {
    Axios.get(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_data=2015-6-3&sol=1000&camera${name}&api_key="MY_API_KEY"/`).then((res) => {
      setFetchedImage(res.data.photos[0].img_src);
      //   console.log(res.data.photos.img_src);
    }, []);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    imageHandler();
  });

  return (
    <section>
      <h3>Astronomy Picture Of The Day</h3>
      <div className="picture">
        <button onClick={() => imageHandler('FHAZ')}>FHAZ</button>
        <button onClick={() => imageHandler('RHAZ')}>RHAZ</button>
        <button onClick={() => imageHandler('MAST')}>MAST</button>
        <button onClick={() => imageHandler('CHEMCAM')}>CHEMCAM</button>
      </div>
      <img src={fetchedImage} alt="" />
    </section>
  );
};

export default PictureOfTheDay;
```

Currently, I am doing something like this but it is just showing me one image I know I have done something stupid but please help me out.

Comment: it is unclear what you want to accomplish but I'm assuming you are expecting more than one result right? in `res.data.photos[0].img_src` you are selecting one item (in the index 0) from that `photos` array so that's probably why you are getting just one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used dummy API.

```
https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY
```

The JSON response sample.

```
{
"id": 102693,
"sol": 1000,
"camera": {
"id": 20,
"name": "FHAZ",
"rover_id": 5,
"full_name": "Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"
},
"img_src": "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01000/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486265257EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG",
"earth_date": "2015-05-30",
"rover": {
"id": 5,
"name": "Curiosity",
"landing_date": "2012-08-06",
"launch_date": "2011-11-26",
"status": "active"
}
},
{
"id": 102694,
"sol": 1000,
...
"img_src": "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01000/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_486265257EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG",
}
},
...
```

Store the data in a useState variable and then map it and show only the image URL[img_src]. Hope it will solve your problem in this way.

```
 const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch("API...")
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data=>setMyData(data));
    }, [])
```

```
        {
            myData.map(myData =><ImageCompo
            key={myData.id}
            myData={myData}
            ></ImageCompo>)
        }
```

In ImageCompo retrieve imag_src props:

```
function ImageCompo({myData}) {
    const{id,img_src}=myData;
```

```
<img src={img_src} alt='' width={200} height={200}></img>
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: but I want to get random images on the click-from button how will I do that?

Comment: @VaibhavKumar looks like you can pass in `date` and generate a random date from the last x amount of years and pass that in as a parameter with your request, in the same way that you're passing in `api_key`. It needs format: `YYYY-MM-DD`, according to https://api.nasa.gov/, this is for APOD, astronomy picture of the day - https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod